# Regular Expression... extract certain word from string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string and I want to extract the location out of it.

```
 {"image_intro":"images\/slider\/lazic.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"Tuttlingen","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"images\/slider\/lazic.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

So I need the word **Tuttlingen** ... and nothing more.

Can somebody tell me the correct regex for **PHP** ?

Comment: You can use in php `json_decode` reference http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: `$s = "Tuttlingen";`. You're welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a nicely formatted JSON string. Using `json_decode()` will be way easier.

```
$string = '{"image_intro":"images\/slider\/lazic.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"Tuttlingen","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"images\/slider\/lazic.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}';
$json = json_decode($string, true);
echo $json['image_intro_alt'];
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for reminding me that. I always forget this.

Comment: While this is technically correct (the best kind of correct), the question is explicitly asking for a RegEx.

Comment: @apokryfos While you're right in that the OP wants a regex, it's important to remember that regex involves a LOT more overhead than a parser incurs. And, in this case, it's much simpler and cleaner code as well. Don't just answer questions, think about how to teach people to code better.

Comment: @apokryfos While the question is explicitly asking for a RegEx, treating the string as JSON and using `json_decode()` achieves the required result, and I believe is cleaner and easier than unnecessary fiddling with regular expressions. The explicit RegEx request might just be the fact that OP is unfamiliar with JSON/`json_decode()`, as there really is no need to use RegExps with this input.

Comment: Thank you very very much ... I searched the whole web for json ... but if you don't know the word ... there is no way ... so thank you it is indeed better than a regex !

Answer (score 1):

```
   $str = '{
      "image_intro": "images\/slider\/lazic.jpg",
      "float_intro": "",
      "image_intro_alt": "Tuttlingen",
      "image_intro_caption": "",
      "image_fulltext": "images\/slider\/lazic.jpg",
      "float_fulltext": "",
      "image_fulltext_alt": "",
      "image_fulltext_caption": ""
   }';
   $res = null;
   $regex = "/.*\"image\_intro\_alt\"\:\s*\"(.*?)\".*/";
   preg_match($regex,$str,$res);
   if (is_array($res) && isset($res[1])) {
        echo $res[1]; //Echo or do whatever with it.
   }
```

Updated: Made the matching lazy as suggested